# 3 RVs with equal Marginal distribution...

Tags: probability

Question:
$X_1,X_2,X_3$ are RVs. 
The marginal distribution of these RVs are equal.
$$P(X_1+X_2+X_3=9)=P(\min{X_1,X_2,X_3}>=0) = 1 $$

Which one of the following inequalities necessarily hold?

- A. $P(X_1\leq 2)\leq {6 \over 7}$
- B. $P(X_1>X_2)>0$
- C. $P(X_1 \geq 2)\leq {2 \over 3}$
- D. None of the above holds necessarily.

I know for sure B is not the right answer since I can define the RVs s.t $X_1<X_2$, but for the rest of the questions I don't know how to prove correctness/incorrectness.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure there is no typo? One would expect the condition that $P(X_1\leqslant2)\leqslant\frac23$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll rearrange it so we could fit it into Markov's inequality:
$P(X1 \leq 2)\leq $ $ 6 \over 7  $

$X_1+X_2+X_3=9$ therefore $X_1=9-X_2-X_3$
and also $E[X_1+X_2+X_3]=9 $ and from the marginal dist. equality we get $E[X_1]=E[X_2]=E[X_3]=3$

$P(9-X_2-X_3 \leq 2)=P(7 \leq X_2+X_3)  \leq $$E[X_2+X_3] \over 7$ = $6 \over 7$